# Error loading MySQLdb module. Did you install mysqlclient?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

```
File "C:\Users\bhavika\demo\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 17, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

having an error while running the code for database connectivity in python django

i have tried multiple ways but not getting the output

```
DATABASES = {
"default": {
    "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",
    "NAME": "mydata",
    "USER": "root",
    "PASSWORD": "",
    "HOST": "localhost",
    "PORT": "3306",
    "OPTIONS" : {
        'init_command' : "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *i have tried multiple ways but not getting the output* - Please [edit] your question and include the code that you have tried with or make a [mre], then we can help you troubleshoot any issues you might have with that. To learn more about how the [SO] community can help you, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",
        "NAME": "mydata",
        "USER": "root",
        "PASSWORD": "",
        "HOST": "localhost",
        "PORT": "3306",
        "OPTIONS" : {
            'init_command' : "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'"
        }
    }
} in settings.py file and i also installed mysql client

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code there, not in the comments.

Comment: why this type of error can occur?